# Usage of 一边 (doing things simultaneously)?

Tags: translation, grammar, adverbs

Is this the correct way of saying "she is taking a bath while listening to music"?

> 她一边洗澡，一边听音乐。

Comment: Yes your translation is correct

Answer (score 5):

“一边。。。一边。。。” is a very useful structure. It can also be simplified as “边。。。边。。。”

For example, 他一边吃饭一边看书。她边走边唱。

Comment: This does not answer the question and should not be published as an answer.